# Spring data save

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Сущности

**Acc**

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"remoteId", "owner"})
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"uuid", "locale_id"}))
public class Acc extends SynchronizedEntity implements Limit.OwnerOfLimit {
private Long mId;

@ManyToOne
@JsonProperty("owner")
private User mOwner;
@JsonProperty("userId")
private String mUserId;
@JsonProperty("name")
private String mName;
@JsonProperty("cur")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Cur mCur;

@JsonProperty("accType")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private AccType mAccType;

@JsonProperty("colorId")
private String mColorId;
@JsonProperty("rest")
private Float mRest;
@JsonProperty("order")
private Long mOrder;
@JsonProperty("limitOwner")
private String limitOwner;
```

**Cur**

```
@Entity
@Immutable
public class Cur extends BaseEntity {
    @JsonProperty("iso")
    private String mIso;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String mName;
    @JsonProperty("use")
    private String mUse = "N";
}
```

**AccType**

```
@Entity
@Immutable
public class AccType extends BaseEntity {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String mName;
    @JsonProperty("ap")
    private short mAp;
    @JsonProperty("iconid")
    private String mIconid;
}
```

`REST` сервер (`Spring`) обрабатывает запрос с объектом **Acc** и выполняет действие сохранение, обновления, помечает на удаление.
Я захотел сделать так, чтобы таблицы **cur** и **AccType** были справочниками (так-как в **AccType** всего 3 поля,а в **Cur** 160). Но теперь, когда я пытаюсь сохранить свежеприсланный обьект в бд через его DAO обычным методом save у меня вылетает ошибка , а именно

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
>   execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not
>   execute statement
>       Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности
>   "cur_pkey"
>         Подробности: Ключ "(id)=(2)" уже существует.

Как я понимаю hibernate пытается записать обьект в табличку **cur** и естественно не может это сделать, так как поле уже занято. НО суть в том, что он не должен создавать поле, а должен находить уже созданное в справочнике поле и в **Acc** добавлять его.

Есть ли какая-нибудь аннотация, которая запрещает запись и говорит ,что нужно искать по таким данных поле, а не создавать

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь то дело в `@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` нужно отключить каскадное обновление.

Comment: После удаления выкидывает  object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing 
Но мне не нужно чтобы он сохранял поле, мне нужно забрать уже готовое из справочника

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
```